# Correct WS-Policy for UsernameToken and CXF SOAP WS

Tags: cxf

I have following annotation on my SOAP Web Service:

`@Policy(uri = "classpath:/ws/soap/UsernameTokenPolicy.xml")`

and such Endpoint configuration:

```
Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);

WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

endpoint.getProperties().put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN_VALIDATOR, authenticationPlugin);
```

This is the the content of `UsernameTokenPolicy.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
    <sp:SupportingTokens>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken/>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The client sends such security header:

```
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-FA33408419A5268E38151818972919430">
        <wsse:Username>USERABC</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">123456789</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
```

and CXF Server rejects the policy:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 

    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}UsernameToken
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. According to [this document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/security-policy/examples/ws-sp-usecases-examples.html#_Toc274723237) my policy looks all right (`sp:IncludeToken` does not change anything).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I need Policy Aware Interceptor as first one:

```
PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor pwssIn = new PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor();
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(pwssIn);

Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

endpoint.getProperties().put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN_VALIDATOR, authenticationPlugin);
```

Comment: You don't need to specify "WSS4JInInterceptor" at all, as CXF will take care of adding the correct security interceptors for the policy-driven case.

Comment: I've tried to remove it, but in such case, it disables ws-security, maybe I'm missing something in configuration....

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. It seems that CXF has like a default interceptor for policies called PolicyVerificationInInterceptor throwing this error. But I don't know how to configure or overwrite it.